# Deleted PocketMine, now Realms sign-in is broken

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I accidentally deleted PocketMine on my iPod. Now I can't login to Realms on Minecraft PE. When I go and click on the login button on the Play on Realms screen, all I get is a white page saying "the file public/m/ does not exist".

Comment: [PocketMine](https://www.pocketmine.net/) is a Minecraft server mod, making this question off-topic as tech support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install PocketMine again, because without it you will get an error. Reinstalling Minecraft PE and anything associated with it may also solve the problem, although you will get the normal Realms screen instead of all of the PocketMine servers.

Comment: Thanks for help. Also, not sure why my post was edited, since it was PocketMine that was deleted, not MinecraftPE.  Anyways, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I saw your post before it was edited.